# joomla photo display on home page and photo gallery

Tags: joomla

a)I want to allow the user to upload the photos from the front-end
b)Latest photos are needed to be displayed in the left menu (max 8)
c)A separate page for displaying all the photos after clicking of photo, will show the full size photo with next and previous button.

I don't know which component or module will suit these requirements in joomla.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JoomGallery:
http://www.en.joomgallery.net/